# matplotlib's detrend_linear shows deviation in detrending sin(t)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Testing matplotlib's `detrend_linear` function with

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import detrend_linear

n = 1000
t = np.arange(n)
y = np.sin(8.*np.pi/n*t) # exactly 4 periods

plt.plot(y, label='raw')
plt.plot(detrend_linear(y), label='detrended')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

shows a clear deviation:
[image]

I excepted the trend line to be horizontal and to see no difference.
Where has my thinking gone wrong?

Thanks for any suggestions, dietrich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trend in the sine function, since it is not symmetrical in that domain. Try it with 4.5 periods and the trend should be gone.

Comment: Thank you very much - that was the hint I needed, dietrich!